# ArtifactDescriptorException while adding dependency mockito 1.10.19 version

Tags: java, maven

While adding the following dependency in pom.xml file, getting ArtifactDescriptorException

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Issue:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.mockito:mockito-all:pom:1.10.19 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.mockito:mockito-all:pom:1.10.19 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org  pom.xml /mockito-example    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

However, it is working fine with the 1.10.18 or 1.10.17

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.18</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I don't understand what is the issue with 1.10.19 version.
Any help would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like an earlier download attempt failed.  As the message says, `resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced` - typically the update interval is 24 hours.

If you haven't tried it already, suggest using the force updates option - `mvn -U`.  (If this is in Eclipse, judging by the column titles, look for `Force Update` in the `Maven`/`Update project` dialog).

Just for reference, the same artifact version is downloading fine from over here.

Comment: Thanks, Clicking on (Maven -> Update Project -> Checked "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" -> Click OK) worked.